# Plot heatmap from Table of coordinates and colormap

Tags: plotting

I want to draw

```
Table[{a, b, c}, {a, 0.1, 1, 1}, {b, 0.1, 1, 1}, {c, 11, 15, 0.05}]
```

via heatmap in *Mathematica* where I choose `a` along x-axis and `b` along y-axis and `c` as a colormap.

But failed to draw it. Please anybody help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the **[tour]** so you learn the basics of the site. What have you tried? Did you search the documentation and the site for similar problems? Did you find something close to your question? How is your question different from what you found? Don't make us guess. Please **[edit]** your question to improve it.

Comment: Ask yourself: Did you give us enough to work on your problem? [We expect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

✅ A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌ A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌ An example of what you expect as output.
❌ Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge.
❌ Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: Do you mean something like [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/ListDensityPlot.html)?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You crate a table of coordinates, but you do not specify any function values?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually I am working on Fractals via fixed point iterations. I used Mann iteration to generate Mandelbrot set of complex polynomial Z^2+C^(phi). The composition of Mann iteration for this polynomial is as follows:

Comment: Now I want to make a graph between a from 0.1 to 1 along X-axis, b from 0.1 to 1  along Y-axis and time t (average image generation time) for each (a,b) as a color function.  Like heatmap

Comment: I have a Mann iteration like: (1-a)*Z+a*(Z^2+C^b). When i iterate it, quadratic Mandelbrot set generate in 11 seconds for a=0.1 and b=0.1. I want to draw a graph using heatmap for a=0.1 to 1 along X-axix, b=0.1 to 1 along Y-axis and choose time as color function

Comment: I want to take 100 values of a and b between 0.1 to 1. These values will provide me 100 values of time. For this data i want to draw heatmap.

Comment: Actually the points takes the form (a,b,t).

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, b_] := a + b

data = Flatten[
   Table[
    {a, b, f[a, b]},
    {a, 0.1, 1, .1}, {b, 0.1, 1, .1}],
   1];
```

Verifying that `data` has proper dimensions

```
Dimensions@data

(* {100, 3} *)

ListDensityPlot[data,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"a", "b"}),
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotLabel -> Style["Plot Title", 14],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> "Whatever"]]
```

[image]